# Why is there no dropdown icon on the Form.Control component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I created a drop-down select list so a user can choose the quantity of the product he/she wants. The problem is, that there is no drop-down mark (?) on the right of the list.

```
                                    { product.countInStock > 0 && (
                                        <ListGroup.Item>
                                            <Row>
                                                <Col>Quantity:</Col>
                                                <Col xs="auto" className="my-1">
                                                    <Form.Control
                                                        as="select"
                                                        value={ quantity }
                                                        onChange={ (e) => setQuantity(e.target.value) }
                                                    >
                                                        { [...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map(
                                                            (x) => <option key={x} value={x + 1}>{x + 1}</option>
                                                        )}
                                                    </Form.Control>
                                                </Col>
                                            </Row>
                                        </ListGroup.Item>
                                    ) }
```

This is how it looks like at this moment:

[image]

and this is how it should properly look like:

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Adding your html file would be helpful to debug this one.

Comment: @Danny sorry I am kinda newby in this topic. I am using Django, React and Bootstrap to create this functionality. That's the snippet from my Screen component.